# Multiple bxsliders on one page. Is it possible to combine js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

Is it possbile to combine JS of 4 [Bxsliders](http://bxslider.com/) that I have on one page? Please see JS below.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.bxslider2').bxSlider({
 slideWidth: 645,
 minSlides: 3,
 maxSlides: 3,
 moveSlides: 1,
 slideMargin: 0,
 responsive: false,
 controls: true,
 onSliderLoad: function () {
     $('.bxslider2 > li:not(.bx-clone)').eq(1).addClass('active-slide');
 },
 onSlideBefore: function ($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex) {
     $('.bxslider2 li').removeClass('active-slide');
     $($slideElement).next().addClass('active-slide');        
 }
    });
});
```

I am not good at JS, but I'm sure there is a way to combine that JS, so it's only typed once (rather than copy > paste 4x times with different classes .bxslider2, .bxslider3 etc..) I need to make sure that first slide on each carousel has that class .active-slide.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function makeOnSliderLoad(index) {
        return function() {
            $('.bxslider' + String(index) + ' > li:not(.bx-clone)').eq(1).addClass('active-slide');
        }
    }   

    function makeOnSlideBefore(index) {
        return function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex) {
                $('.bxslider' + String(index) + ' li').removeClass('active-slide');
                $($slideElement).next().addClass('active-slide');        
        }
    }

    for(var sliderIndex = 1; sliderIndex < 5; sliderIndex++) {
        $('.bxslider' + String(sliderIndex)).bxSlider({
            slideWidth: 645,
            minSlides: 3,
            maxSlides: 3,
            moveSlides: 1,
            slideMargin: 0,
            responsive: false,
            controls: true,
            onSliderLoad: makeOnSliderLoad(sliderIndex),
            onSlideBefore: makeOnSlideBefore(sliderIndex)
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I have tried this and it kind of works, but now it doesn't remove class .active-slide once it's added. Any ideas?